# How to set title for each dropdownitem in a dropdownlist MVC5

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

**Controller**

```
public void setViewBags()
{
    List<GroepModel> groepen = Mapper.Map<List<GroepenWerkvorm>, List<GroepModel>>(db.GroepenWerkvorms.ToList());

    var groepmodel = new DropDownModel();
    groepmodel.list = new SelectList(groepen, "id", "Naam");
    ViewBag.groepmodel = groepmodel;
}
```

**View:**

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.selectedItem, ViewBag.groepmodel.list as IEnumerable<SelectListItem>,"Selecteer een groep", new { @class = "groepen" })
```

Each of my elements in `groepen` has a property called description. I'd like to set the title of each element in the dropdown to the according description, so the user can hover over them to see the description.

I'm assuming I'd probably need JQuery to do this?

```
var i = 0;
$('.groepen option').each(function(){
$(this).attr('title',// Get the correct description somehow?)
i++;
});
```

I'm guessing this would probably work, but how do I get the correct description for each element?

Comment: I'm a little conflicted on what you're asking for. Do you want to change a title somewhere on the page when the drop down list is changed or have a hover event over each different element in the drop down list?

Comment: The second, hower event over each element

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `DropDownListFor` helper has no support for setting additional attributes on the generated `option` elements. If you need to set something like a `title` attribute, you'll need to generate your options manually:

```
<select id="@Html.IdFor(m => m.selectedItem)" name="@Html.NameFor(m => m.selectedItem)">
    @foreach (var groepModel in groepen)
    {
        <option value="@groepModel.id" title="@groepModel.Description">@groepModel.Naam</option>
    }
</select>
```

Comment: Simple and clean. Thanks!

Comment: Just be aware this means no 2-way model binding and no client side validation

Comment: Well, that's true in as much as the current code does not account for either of those things. The long and short with this method is everything has to be done manually, as you're not using the helper, but you can get 1-to-1 parity if you take it that far.